# Standalone VLC Browser Plugin

Tags: plugins, vlc, firebreath

I want to embed the VLC player on my website, but I don't want to force users to leave the webpage, download the VLC application and install it.  A plugin installation would be much cleaner in my opinion.

Is there a standalone browser plugin for VLC for the supported OS/browser combinations (ie. Linux/MAC/Windows, NPAPI/ActiveX)?  From the documentation and installers I don't see a standalone option.

[FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home) looks really interesting, and there is a [FireBreath VLC plugin](https://code.google.com/p/fbvlc/), but right now only Windows is supported by it.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it, but [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/) has [portable VLC](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable)